# How to calculate the big-O estimate of this formula?

Tags: trigonometry

The formula is as follows,

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{i}_{j=1}\frac{(n-j)\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2\sin\theta}\sin[2(j-n)\theta]}{\sin[(n-j+2)\theta]\sin[(n-j+1)\theta]}$$
and this formula is independent of i.According to some paper, the result should be $n^2$,but I just can't figure out how to do this.
Many thanks!

Comment: There are about $n^2/2$ terms, so if you can show that each is bounded, you are done. The form of the denominator suggests to me looking at the formula for sin(a)sin(b) in terms of cos(a+b) and cos(a-b).

Comment: @martycohen:  but each one is about $n$, so we should have $O(n^3)$, which is what I am getting.

Comment: Perhaps the paper is wrong. Does it prove the result or just state it?

Comment: @martycohen The paper just state this fact.Maybe it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get that,
for small $\theta$,
the sum is
$\frac49 n^3+O(n^2)$
independent of $\theta$.

In what follows,
I write $t$ for $\theta$
because lazy.

$s(t, n)
=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{i}_{j=1}\frac{(n-j)\cos t+\frac{1}{2\sin t}\sin[2(j-n)t]}{\sin[(n-j+2)t]\sin[(n-j+1)t]}
=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{i}_{j=1} r(t, n-j)
$
where
$r(t, k)
=\frac{k\cos t+\frac{1}{2\sin t}\sin[-2kt]}{\sin[(k+2)t]\sin[(k+1)t]}
=\frac{k\cos t-\frac{\sin[2kt]}{2\sin t}}{\sin[(k+2)t]\sin[(k+1)t]}
$

The sum can be simplified.

$\begin{array}\\
s(t, n)
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{i}_{j=1} r(t, n-j)\\
&=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\sum^{n}_{i=j} r(t, n-j)\\
&=\sum^{n}_{j=1}(n-j+1) r(t, n-j)\\
&=\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}(j+1) r(t, j)\\
\end{array}
$

Let's look at
the difference in the numerator.

$d(t, k)
=k\cos t-\frac{\sin[2kt]}{2\sin t}
$.
For small $t$,
since
$\cos(t) \approx 1-t^2/2$
and
$\sin(t) \approx t-t^3/6$,

$\begin{array}\\
d(t, k)
&\approx k(1-t^2/2)-\frac{2kt-(2kt)^3/6}{2(t-t^3/6)}\\
&= k(1-t^2/2)-\frac{k-4k^3t^2/3}{1-t^2/6}\\
&\approx k(1-t^2/2)-k(1-4k^2t^2/3)(1+t^2/6)\\
&\approx k(1-t^2/2)-k(1-t^2(4k^2/3-1/6))\\
&= t^2k(4k^2/3-1/6-1/2))\\
&= t^2k(4k^2-2)/3\\
&= 2t^2k(2k^2-1)/3\\
\end{array}
$

Note:
This is the key approximation here.
The error term is
of order $t^4$ with some coefficient
that depends on $k$
that I am too lazy to 
work out.
Accounting for this
might make the result larger,
but almost certainly not smaller.

Therefore,
for small $t$,

$\begin{array}\\
r(t, k)
&=\frac{k\cos t-\frac{1}{2\sin t}\sin[2kt]}{\sin[(k+2)t]\sin[(k+1)t]}\\
&\approx \frac{2t^2k(2k^2-1)/3}{(k+1)(k+2)t^2}\\
&= \frac{2k(2k^2-1)}{3(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&=\frac43 k + O(1)\\
\end{array}
$

so that

$\begin{array}\\
s(t, n)
&=\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}(j+1) r(t, j)\\
&\approx\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}(j+1) (\frac43 j +O(1))\\
&\approx\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}(\frac43 j^2 +O(j))\\
&=\frac43 \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}+O(n^2)\\
&=\frac49 n^3+O(n^2)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: thank you so much!so the paper is wrong~

Answer (score 0):

All the sines and cosines are bounded by $1$, so for big-O calculations can be ignored as long as the sines in the denominator do not become too small.  We then have $$\begin {align}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{i}_{j=1}n-j&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}ni-i(i+1)/2\\&=n^2(n+1)/2-n(n+1)(2n+1)/12-n(n+1)/4\\ &\in O(n^3)\end {align}$$